# compare two range and add missing entries by inserting a new row?

Tags: vba, excel, compare, range

I have two ranges (A4:C13) and (E4:G13) and i want to compare column A (A4:A13) with Column E (E4:E13) if any of the value is missing in either columns then it should add missing value and fill other rows with 0 as shown attached image. Any idea how to achieve this?. so far i have found the following code it adds the value in one column but not in another. Should i run this code for another column or is there any other simple way to do it?.

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim cl As Range

Set cl = Range("D1")

Do While cl.Row < 10
  If cl.Value <> cl.Offset(0, -3).Value Then
    cl.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    cl.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Set cl = cl.Offset(-1, 0)
  End If
  Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub Rng_Compare_B()
Dim RngA As Range, RngB As Range
Dim lValA As Long, lValB As Long
Dim vMatch As Variant, lRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet.Rows(4)
        Set RngA = .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set RngB = .Cells(5).CurrentRegion
    End With

    Do

        lRow = 1 + lRow
        lValA = RngA.Cells(lRow, 1).Value2
        lValB = RngB.Cells(lRow, 1).Value2

        If lValA = Empty And lValB = Empty Then Exit Do

        Rem Compares Range A vs B - Adjust B
        If lValA <> Empty Then
            vMatch = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            vMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(lValA, RngB.Columns(1), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If vMatch = 0 Then
                RngB.Rows(lRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                RngB.Rows(lRow).Value = Array(lValA, 0, 0)
                GoTo Loop_Next
        End If: End If

        Rem Compares Range B vs A - Adjust A
        If lValB <> Empty Then
            vMatch = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            vMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(lValB, RngA.Columns(1), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If vMatch = 0 Then
                RngA.Rows(lRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                RngA.Rows(lRow).Value = Array(lValB, 0, 0)
        End If: End If

Loop_Next:
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This one does it in place:

```
Sub testdddd()
Dim cl1 As Range
Dim cl2 As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim fnd As Range
Dim arr() As Variant
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown))
    Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(4, 5), .Cells(4, 5).End(xlDown))
    'rng2.Select
    For Each cl1 In rng1
        Set fnd = rng2.Find(cl1)
        If fnd Is Nothing Then
            arr = Array(cl1, 0, 0)
            rng2.Cells(rng2.Rows.count + 1, 1).Resize(, 3) = arr
            Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(4, 5), .Cells(4, 5).End(xlDown))

        End If
    Next cl1

    rng2.Resize(rng2.Rows.count, 3).Sort rng2.Cells(1, 1)

    For Each cl2 In rng2
    Set fnd = rng1.Find(cl2)
    If fnd Is Nothing Then
        arr = Array(cl2, 0, 0)
        rng1.Cells(rng1.Rows.count + 1, 1).Resize(, 3) = arr
        Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(4, 1).End(xlDown))
        rng1.Select
    End If
    Next cl2
    rng1.Resize(rng1.Rows.count, 3).Sort rng1.Cells(1, 1)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for both ..both are working good. I would like to mark both as answers.

Comment: @Shan Mark the one that you use as the correct and give the other a +1.